# while setting Google + account ... getting error: "couldn't find the server"

Tags: localization

While setting Google + account ... getting  error: "couldn't find the server". Please assist, non of the app is working in my mobile (App like: you tube; play store etc.).

Have already tried to delete my Google account and re- create it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a hard reset on your mobile by removing the SDcard and SIM card  but make sure you are  taking a backup of the data that you have on the mobile . You can even try a factory reset option under settings . After doing this try to create an account .